# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) when the model is taken off queue

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax-startup, cqlengine

My intention is to create the `cqlengine.models.Model` instance in a separate process and send it via queue to the database manager.

Unfortunatelly I am getting the TypeError if the `multiprocessing` `queue` is used

#### The model

```python
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns 
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model

class MyModel(Model):
    __keyspace__='mykeyspace'

    class Meta:
        get_pk_field = 'uid'

    uid = columns.UUID(partition_key = True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    start = columns.TimeUUID(primary_key = True, clustering_order='desc')
    interrupt = columns.List(columns.Tuple(columns.TimeUUID(),columns.TimeUUID(), columns.Text()))
    stop = columns.TimeUUID()
```

#### Example

Following code connects to the Cassandra database, creates a model instance and stores it into the database:

```python
    from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
    from vo.record import MyModel

    import uuid

    #Queue
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    #Connect to the database
    connection.setup(('localhost',),'mykeyspace')

    #Create uuid for the record
    uuid = uuid.uuid1()
    #Prepare the new record
    wt = Workingtime(start = uuid, uid = uuid)

    #Store it
    wt.save()
```

However, if I put the model in the queue and dequeue it later, the TypeError is raised.

```python
    queue.put(wt)
    item = queue.get()
    item.save()
```

If the model property _timeout is printed out, the two distinct objects id are shown (as expected)

```python
print wt._timeout
print item._timeout
```

Output:

```
<object object at 0x76d32508>
<object object at 0x76d32e28>
```

#### Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    item.save() 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/models.py", line 731, in save
    if_exists=self._if_exists).save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 1437, in save
    return self.update()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 1420, in update
    self._delete_null_columns(delete_conditionals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 1369, in _delete_null_columns
    self._execute(ds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 1334, in _execute
    results = _execute_statement(self.model, statement, self._consistency, self._timeout, connection=connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 1485, in _execute_statement
    return conn.execute(s, params, timeout=timeout, connection=connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py", line 286, in execute
    result = conn.session.execute(query, params, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1998, in execute
    return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state).result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2038, in execute_async
    future.send_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3365, in send_request
    self._start_timer()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3316, in _start_timer
    self._timer = self.session.cluster.connection_class.create_timer(self._time_remaining, self._on_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/io/asyncorereactor.py", line 289, in create_timer
    timer = Timer(timeout, callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/connection.py", line 1030, in __init__
    self.end = time.time() + timeout
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'object'
```

#### How do I prevent the error?

Comment: Disclosure: I didn't know anything about Cassandra before today. I am curious what `timeout` actually is when it fails. I suspect that knowing that will help debug. I think that the `_timeout` attribute on `wt` (inherited from BaseModel) is what gets passed down and becomes `timeout` on the failing line. So you might try printing out `item._timeout` before calling `item.save()`.

Comment: Also one nitpick. You pass `wt` in the call to `queue.get`. That doesn't actually do anything since `wt` takes the place of the `block` parameter which is true by default and `wt` will always be true anyway.

Comment: @FamousJameous Thanks, it is a mistype

Answer (score 1):

The timeout must be explicitly defined:

```python
wt.timeout(0)
```

I am not able to explain why the save() does not work with multiprocessing queue.